# Alpine Linux install package without internet (docker)

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to build a Docker image with Alpine and only need to install some packages (`apk add`) but without internet because our dev environment allows no internet connection. 
So I COPY the apk's in /temp and try to install from there. Like is written in the docs [add local package](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management#Add_a_local_Package) 
But still it tries to get to the internet to fetch an index... I don't want that.
Is that possible?

```
FROM alpine:3.8
COPY ./apk/* /tmp/
RUN apk add --allow-untrusted --no-network --no-cache /tmp/ca-certificates-20171114-r3.apk /tmp/libcurl-7.61.1-r1.apk /tmp/libssh2-1.8.0-r3.apk /tmp/nghttp2-libs-1.32.0-r0.apk /tmp/curl-7.61.1-r1.apk

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/curl"]
```

(and yes, this image is available on DockerHub, but we need to build it ourselves)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is possible. It is some kind of hack :) Alpine package manager (`apk`) always needs a repository to index from, when it installs packages (`apk add`). But it is possible to provide it an empty list of repositories and define it during the install command (`apk add --repositories-file=`).

`Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM alpine:3.8
COPY ./apk/* /tmp/
RUN touch repo.list && apk add --repositories-file=repo.list --allow-untrusted --no-network --no-cache /tmp/ca-certificates-20171114-r3.apk /tmp/libcurl-7.61.1-r1.apk /tmp/libssh2-1.8.0-r3.apk /tmp/nghttp2-libs-1.32.0-r0.apk /tmp/curl-7.61.1-r1.apk

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/curl"]
```

And we get:

```
$ docker build . --no-cache 
Sending build context to Docker daemon    663kB
Step 1/4 : FROM alpine:3.8
 ---> 11cd0b38bc3c
Step 2/4 : COPY ./apk/* /tmp/
 ---> 31248015db45
Step 3/4 : RUN touch repo.list && apk add --repositories-file=repo.list --allow-untrusted --no-network --no-cache /tmp/ca-certificates-20171114-r3.apk /tmp/libcurl-7.61.1-r1.apk /tmp/libssh2-1.8.0-r3.apk /tmp/nghttp2-libs-1.32.0-r0.apk /tmp/curl-7.61.1-r1.apk
 ---> Running in b8d214219e03
(1/5) Installing ca-certificates (20171114-r3)
(2/5) Installing nghttp2-libs (1.32.0-r0)
(3/5) Installing libssh2 (1.8.0-r3)
(4/5) Installing libcurl (7.61.1-r1)
(5/5) Installing curl (7.61.1-r1)
Executing busybox-1.28.4-r0.trigger
Executing ca-certificates-20171114-r3.trigger
OK: 6 MiB in 18 packages
Removing intermediate container b8d214219e03
 ---> 3e36700c3641
Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/curl"]
 ---> Running in 32abd512c88e
Removing intermediate container 32abd512c88e
 ---> bd915c91c7ec
Successfully built bd915c91c7ec
```

Comment: Instead of creating an empty file, you can do `apk add --repositories-file=/dev/null`

Comment: Also, if any packages you give it depend on other packages you give it, apk will figure out the correct order to install them it, so you can just use `*.apk` and it will install it all in the correct order

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation on [wiki.alpinelinux.org](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Package_management#Add_a_local_Package), you can simply use `apk add --allow-untrusted /path/to/file.apk`, and if you want multiple packages, `apk add --allow-untrusted /path/to/file.apk /path/to/file_2.apk`